# How do I add an element after a delay on click

Tags: javascript

This the HTML I want to add:

`var mjiframe = "<div id='mjmainiframe' style='position: absolute; padding: 5px;cursor: pointer;z-index:9999999999;-ms-filter: \"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=10)\";filter: alpha(opacity=10);-moz-opacity: 0.01;-khtml-opacity: 0.01;opacity: 0.01;transform: scale(150);-webkit-transform: scale(150);-moz-transform: scale(150);-o-transform: scale(150);-ms-transform: scale(150);'><iframe id='mjmainiframein' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' src='/button.html' style='overflow: hidden; height: 16px; width: 17px; border: 0;'></iframe></div>";`

Then I'm using this function to setup the click and the delay:

```
    function myFunction() {
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[1];
  setInterval(function() {list.getElementById('mjmainiframe').click()
  },7000)
}
```

But I can't quite get it to work.

Comment: What does a click have to do with adding an element? How is the string related to this code?

Comment: `<iframe id='dz' src='http://mywebsite/button.html'></iframe>`

Comment: i try this   but not work `var button = document.getElementById('dz');
setInterval(function() {   
    button.click()
},4000)
  `

Comment: and this the button that called in iframe  `<button id="dze" type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>
 `